# Is AGGREGATE FILTER expect case sensitive query expression in Redisearch?

Tags: caching, redis, stackexchange.redis, redis-cache, redisearch

I am using Redisearch module in Redis and trying to filter the data stored in Redis index using the following query.

FT.AGGREGATE MyIndex * GROUPBY 1 "@MyField" FILTER "@MyField=='value'"

I am able to get the result only for the exact word searched, but not when searched with lower case letters for a field having upper case letters and vice versa. Eg: if a field is having 'test' as value, query with "@MyField=='TEST'" or "@MyField=='Test'" doesn't work.

Kindly suggest anything possible.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `lower()` function on both sides.

```
"lower(@MyField) == lower('TEST')"
```